# VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime

Tags: virtualbox, debian, crunchbang

```
virtualbox
VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3: symbol krb5int_buf_len, version krb5support_0_MIT not defined in file libkrb5support.so.0 with link time reference

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

I cant launch Virtualbox at all. It was working perfectly fine yesterday but I tried using it today and it is now not working. Tried: sudo apt-get install virtualbox*  and I have also tried installing the .debs on the virtualbox website but nothing helps.
Im using the latest crunchbang.

Comment: I ended up doing a sudo apt-get dist-upgrade in the end to resolve the issue as it got so bad I couldnt get anything X related to show up. Not a solution, but its soemthing.

Answer (score 5):

Like described at https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16759.
This fixed my problem (virtualbox 5.1.26r117224, kernel 4.10.0-33)

```
sudo chown root:root /usr 
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib 
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/virtualbox
```

Comment: worked for me, although reinstalling virtualbox didn't. This should be the answer.

Comment: From my experience, besides `chown`, `chmod 755` permissions must be set on these directories as well as `/usr/local`, `/usr/local/etc/`, `/usr/local/lib/`

Answer (score 1):

This sequence of commands perfectly solved the same problem on several Gentoo boxes. 
VirtualBox 5.1.30_Gentoo r118389

```
sudo chown root:root /usr 
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib 
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/virtualbox
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing a package from the Debian Unstable repository.

What I did was:

1. Remove the Debian Unstable Repo from /etc/apt/sources.list
2. Update.

   apt-get update
3. Purge Virtualbox

   apt-get purge virtualbox*
4. Reboot.
5. Install Kerberos Server:

   aptitude install krb5-{admin-server,kdc}

in this step, I didn't select the first solution (not install the packages). Then, I selected the second one, a path of about 14 changes, but the most relevant were the downgrade of the packages:

```
libkrb5support0:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7 ==> 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
libkrb5-3:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7 ==> 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7 ==> 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
```

6-. Install the package Virtualbox from repository, or with the .debs on the virtualbox website.

I don't have screenshots, but I got the entries in the log /var/log/dpkg.log may be it's useful for anyone:

```
2014-08-19 18:22:20 startup packages remove
2014-08-19 18:22:20 status installed libcups2:i386 1.7.5-1
2014-08-19 18:22:20 remove libcups2:i386 1.7.5-1 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:20 status half-configured libcups2:i386 1.7.5-1
2014-08-19 18:22:20 status half-installed libcups2:i386 1.7.5-1
2014-08-19 18:22:21 status config-files libcups2:i386 1.7.5-1
2014-08-19 18:22:21 status config-files libcups2:i386 1.7.5-1
2014-08-19 18:22:21 status installed libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:21 remove libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:21 status half-configured libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:21 status half-installed libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:22 status config-files libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:22 status config-files libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:22 status installed libkrb5-3:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:22 remove libkrb5-3:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:22 status half-configured libkrb5-3:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:22 status half-installed libkrb5-3:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:22 status config-files libkrb5-3:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:22 status config-files libkrb5-3:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:22 status installed libk5crypto3:i386 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:22 remove libk5crypto3:i386 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:22 status half-configured libk5crypto3:i386 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:22 status half-installed libk5crypto3:i386 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:23 status config-files libk5crypto3:i386 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:23 status config-files libk5crypto3:i386 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:23 status installed libkrb5support0:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:23 remove libkrb5support0:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:23 status half-configured libkrb5support0:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:23 status half-installed libkrb5support0:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:23 status config-files libkrb5support0:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:23 status config-files libkrb5support0:i386 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:23 status installed nfs-common:amd64 1:1.2.8-9
2014-08-19 18:22:23 remove nfs-common:amd64 1:1.2.8-9 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:23 status half-configured nfs-common:amd64 1:1.2.8-9
2014-08-19 18:22:24 status half-installed nfs-common:amd64 1:1.2.8-9
2014-08-19 18:22:24 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:24 status half-installed nfs-common:amd64 1:1.2.8-9
2014-08-19 18:22:24 status config-files nfs-common:amd64 1:1.2.8-9
2014-08-19 18:22:24 status config-files nfs-common:amd64 1:1.2.8-9
2014-08-19 18:22:24 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:24 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:25 status installed man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:26 startup archives unpack
2014-08-19 18:22:26 upgrade libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:26 status half-configured libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:27 status unpacked libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:27 status half-installed libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:27 status half-installed libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:27 status unpacked libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:27 status unpacked libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:28 upgrade libkrb5-3:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:28 status half-configured libkrb5-3:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:28 status unpacked libkrb5-3:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:28 status half-installed libkrb5-3:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:28 status half-installed libkrb5-3:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:28 status unpacked libkrb5-3:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:28 status unpacked libkrb5-3:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:28 upgrade libkrb5support0:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:28 status half-configured libkrb5support0:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:28 status unpacked libkrb5support0:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:28 status half-installed libkrb5support0:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:29 status half-installed libkrb5support0:amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-7
2014-08-19 18:22:29 status unpacked libkrb5support0:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:29 status unpacked libkrb5support0:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:29 install libgssrpc4:amd64 <none> 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:29 status half-installed libgssrpc4:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:29 status unpacked libgssrpc4:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:29 status unpacked libgssrpc4:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:30 install libkadm5clnt-mit8:amd64 <none> 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:30 status half-installed libkadm5clnt-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:30 status unpacked libkadm5clnt-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:30 status unpacked libkadm5clnt-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:30 install libkdb5-6:amd64 <none> 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:30 status half-installed libkdb5-6:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:31 status unpacked libkdb5-6:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:31 status unpacked libkdb5-6:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:31 install libkadm5srv-mit8:amd64 <none> 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:31 status half-installed libkadm5srv-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:31 status unpacked libkadm5srv-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:31 status unpacked libkadm5srv-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:32 install libverto1:amd64 <none> 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:32 status half-installed libverto1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:32 status unpacked libverto1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:32 status unpacked libverto1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:32 install libverto-glib1:amd64 <none> 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:32 status half-installed libverto-glib1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:32 status unpacked libverto-glib1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:32 status unpacked libverto-glib1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:33 install krb5-config:all <none> 2.3
2014-08-19 18:22:33 status half-installed krb5-config:all 2.3
2014-08-19 18:22:33 status unpacked krb5-config:all 2.3
2014-08-19 18:22:33 status unpacked krb5-config:all 2.3
2014-08-19 18:22:33 install krb5-user:amd64 <none> 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:33 status half-installed krb5-user:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:34 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:34 status half-installed krb5-user:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:34 status unpacked krb5-user:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:34 status unpacked krb5-user:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:34 install krb5-kdc:amd64 <none> 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:34 status half-installed krb5-kdc:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:34 status half-installed krb5-kdc:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:35 status unpacked krb5-kdc:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:35 status unpacked krb5-kdc:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:35 install krb5-admin-server:amd64 <none> 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:35 status half-installed krb5-admin-server:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:35 status half-installed krb5-admin-server:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:35 status unpacked krb5-admin-server:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:35 status unpacked krb5-admin-server:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:35 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1 2.6.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:35 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:37 status installed man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:37 startup packages configure
2014-08-19 18:22:38 configure libkrb5support0:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:38 status unpacked libkrb5support0:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:38 status half-configured libkrb5support0:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:38 status installed libkrb5support0:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:38 configure libkrb5-3:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:38 status unpacked libkrb5-3:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:38 status half-configured libkrb5-3:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:38 status installed libkrb5-3:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:38 configure libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:38 status unpacked libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:38 status half-configured libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:39 status installed libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:39 configure libgssrpc4:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:39 status unpacked libgssrpc4:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:39 status half-configured libgssrpc4:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:39 status installed libgssrpc4:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:39 configure libkadm5clnt-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:39 status unpacked libkadm5clnt-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:39 status half-configured libkadm5clnt-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:39 status installed libkadm5clnt-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:39 configure libkdb5-6:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:39 status unpacked libkdb5-6:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:39 status half-configured libkdb5-6:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:39 status installed libkdb5-6:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:39 configure libkadm5srv-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:39 status unpacked libkadm5srv-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:40 status half-configured libkadm5srv-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:40 status installed libkadm5srv-mit8:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:40 configure krb5-config:all 2.3 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:40 status unpacked krb5-config:all 2.3
2014-08-19 18:22:40 status half-configured krb5-config:all 2.3
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status installed krb5-config:all 2.3
2014-08-19 18:22:41 configure krb5-user:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status unpacked krb5-user:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status half-configured krb5-user:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status installed krb5-user:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:41 configure libverto1:amd64 0.2.2-1 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status unpacked libverto1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status half-configured libverto1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status installed libverto1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:41 configure libverto-glib1:amd64 0.2.2-1 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status unpacked libverto-glib1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status half-configured libverto-glib1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status installed libverto-glib1:amd64 0.2.2-1
2014-08-19 18:22:41 configure krb5-kdc:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status unpacked krb5-kdc:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status unpacked krb5-kdc:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:41 status half-configured krb5-kdc:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:42 status installed krb5-kdc:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:42 configure krb5-admin-server:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2 <none>
2014-08-19 18:22:42 status unpacked krb5-admin-server:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:42 status unpacked krb5-admin-server:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:42 status half-configured krb5-admin-server:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
2014-08-19 18:22:43 status installed krb5-admin-server:amd64 1.10.1+dfsg-5+deb7u2
```